# How can i make a block follow another block in pygame

Tags: python, math, pygame

I have two blocks, one is controlled by the user. When i move my block, i want the other block to follow me. I tried doing something like this

```py
def follow():
    distance = math.hypot(abs(m.x - p.x), abs(m.y - p.y))
    angle_radians = math.atan2(abs(m.y - p.y), abs(m.x - p.x))
    if distance !=  0:
        p.y += math.sin(angle_radians)
        p.x += math.cos(angle_radians)
```

However, the block  ends up moving in the complete opposite direction to me . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if it moves in opposite direction then maybe change `+=` to `-=`

Comment: Tried that but it dosent work either

Comment: then use `print()` to see values in variable - it helps to see problem.

Comment: code works for me if I remove `abs()` from `atan2()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the algorithm work, you have to operate with floating point numbers. If `m` and `p` are [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects, then the algorithm won't work, `pygame.Rect` operates with integral numbers and the fraction part gets lost.
Note `math.sin(angle_radians)` and `math.cos(angle_radians)` is <= 1.

That means you have to store the positions of the objects in separate variables. Let's assume you have the floating point coordinates (`mx`, `my`) and (`py`, `py`)

You have to find the [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) from (`mx`,  `my`) to (`px`, `py`).
The unit vector can be found by dividing the vector from (`mx`,  `m.y`) to (`px`, `py`) by its length.
The length of a vector can be computed by the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).
Finally multiply the vector by a scale (`step`) that is not greater than the distance between the points and add it to the position. e.g:

```py
stepDist = 1

# vector from (`mx`,  `my`) to (`px`, `py`)
dx, dy = p.y - mx, py - px

# [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)
len = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

if len > 0:
    # [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)
    ndx, ndy = dx/len, dy/len

    # minimum of step size and distance to target
    step = min(len, stepDist)

    # step forward
    px += ndx * step
    py += ndy * step
```

If a `pygame.Rect` object is of need, then the position of the rectangle can be set. e.g:

```py
m.topleft = round(mx), round(my)
p.topleft = round(px), round(py)
```

But not you have to store the positions in (`mx`,  `my`) respectively (`px`, `py`). If you would do `mx, my = m.topleft` respectively `px, py = p.topleft`, then the algorithm will break down, because the fraction component gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

Code works for me if I remove `abs()` from `atan2()`

---

```
import pygame
import random
import math

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25 # for more than 220 it has no time to update screen

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x=SCREEN_WIDTH//2, y=SCREEN_HEIGHT//2):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("image.png").convert()
        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(centerx=x, centery=y)

    def update(self):
        #self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH)
        #self.rect.centery = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        move_x = random.randint(-15, 15)
        move_y = random.randint(-15, 15)
        self.rect.move_ip(move_x,move_y)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class Follower(Player):

    def update(self, player):
        distance = math.hypot(abs(player.rect.x - self.rect.x), abs(player.rect.y - self.rect.y))
        angle_radians = math.atan2((player.rect.y - self.rect.y), (player.rect.x - self.rect.x))

        if distance !=  0:
            self.rect.y += 5*math.sin(angle_radians)
            self.rect.x += 5*math.cos(angle_radians)        

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

player = Player()
follower = Follower(0, 0)

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False


    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    if not pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        player.update()
        follower.update(player)
    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    player.draw(screen)
    follower.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)
    #pygame.display.set_caption('{}ms'.format(ms)) # 40ms for 25FPS, 16ms for 60FPS
    fps = clock.get_fps()
    pygame.display.set_caption('FPS: {}'.format(fps))

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thats kinda weird beacause i was reading how atan2 works and it was it can only accept absolute values

Comment: That won't work for a step distance of 1 and its inaccurate, because [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) operates with integral numbers.

Comment: @Rabbid76 what distance ? I don't use any distance. And I set `5*math.sin` and `5*math.cos` to move faster and I have no problem with small values

Comment: @furas your step distance is 5. (`self.rect.y += 5*math.sin(angle_radians)`). In the question the distance is 1.

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes for `1*math.sin` it doesn't work but for this value it was moving so slow that it was useless. So using `5` I automatically resolved both problems.

Comment: It is too slow in your test application but not in general. Furthermore you will step over the target if the distance between `m` and `p` is < 5.